# How can I build a Rails time object representing a certain day in a certain week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I also have a week number, extracted from another time object like this

```
other_time.strftime('%W').to_i
```

`%W` gives:

> Week number of the year.  The week starts with Monday.  (00..53)

I also have a day name:

```
'Tuesday'
```

How can I build a DateTime object that represents Tuesday in the week indicated by the week number? The time component of the object is irrelevant at this stage, as it will be changed in a later step.

I'm using Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.2p320.

Edit: Incorrectly stated that I wanted a Time object. I actually want a DateTime object.

Comment: "Tuesday" isn't a time. Do you want a date object, or is there a particular time during Tuesday that you're interested in?

Comment: I was mistaken, I want a DateTime object. The actual time set for the object doesn't matter at this stage, because it will be changed in a later step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the day against your desired day, and adjust accordingly. It's not great, but it does work.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :002 > other_date = DateTime.now
 => #<DateTime: 2012-06-08T14:23:44-04:00 ((2456087j,66224s,205565000n),-14400s,2299161j)> 
1.9.3p0 :003 > week = other_date.strftime('%W').to_i
 => 23 
1.9.3p0 :004 > target_day = 2 # Tuesday
 => 2 
1.9.3p0 :005 > while other_date.wday > target_day ; other_date = other_date.prev_day ; end
 => nil 
1.9.3p0 :006 > while other_date.wday < target_day ; other_date = other_date.next_day ; end
 => nil 
1.9.3p0 :007 > other_date # Tuesday of this week
 => #<DateTime: 2012-06-05T14:23:44-04:00 ((2456084j,66224s,205565000n),-14400s,2299161j)> 
1.9.3p0 :008 > other_date.strftime('%W').to_i == week
 => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a DateTime object.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html

Comment: Thanks, I incorrectly said Time object. Still want to know how to build it with those criteria though.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned `other_time`. I'll take advantage of it:

```
other_time.beginning_of_week + DateTime::DAYNAMES.rotate.index('Tuesday').to_i.days
```